From Expansion panel remove arrow
I'm using ExpansionPanel, But i don't want trailing widget arrow, how to remove it.
How to remove down or up arrow from expansion panel, So is there any way to remove it, And is there any custom expantionPanel,
& is there facility to expand Expansion Panel on right?

Anyone know How to remove arrow from expansion panel?

You could use ExpansionTile instead of ExpansionPanel, you can set the trailing widget to any icon you need or even remove it:
   ExpansionTile(
      trailing: SizedBox.shrink(), // removes the icon
      title: Text('ExpansionTile 1'),
      subtitle: Text('Trailing expansion arrow icon'),
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
      ],
    ),

setting trailing to SizeBox.shrink() will remove that arrow icon, note that the children of the Expansion Tile refer to the widgets which will be visible on expand and hidden on collapse.

It's working. Thank You

is it possible to expand on right ?

@MoonPrincess , expand on right! do you mean make the tile open its children on right?

Yes, I wants it has to open at right.

@MoonPrincess how come! can't be achieved through list tile, you need to think of a custom widget

Okay, Thank you.
